# How to use lower version of dependency on conflict in maven project

Tags: scala, maven, pom.xml

I am working on a multi-module maven project, which have the module with different versions of the scala, the reason being the new module say **B** was added which required the higher scala version i.e 2.11 and rest of the project is build around scala 2.10.
Now I have a use case where I need to call a method from the class of **B** to the one with lower version.
which results in the dependency conflict.
Is there any way for which I can define the version of dependencies i.e to use lower version to compile.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what is going on?  Scala versions are not compatible.  You will need to either downgrade B to scala 2.10 or upgrade the whole project to 2.11 (or even better 2.12 if possible)

Comment: You cannot use different versions of same named libraries of classes on your classpath. You need to upgrade your project to use 2.11 version.